# Android Volley to parse JSON and put into listview is not working

Tags: android, json, listview, android-volley

I am using this guide here:

http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/

I put

```
System.out.println(error.getMessage());
```

in my code below and here were the errors it was showing me:

```
01-13 18:53:21.425 1915-1915/com.app.dev.myapplication I/System.out: org.json.JSONException: Value {"server_response":[{"first_name":"bob","last_name":"john","user_name":"bobthebuilder","avatar":"stringOfURL"}]} of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray
01-13 18:53:21.425 1915-1915/com.app.dev.myapplication D/Volley: [1] 2.onErrorResponse: SearchActivity
```

Here is my JSON Code:

```
{"server_response":[{"first_name":"bob","last_name":"john","user_name":"bobthebuilder","avatar":"stringOfURL"}]}
```

Here is my code:

```
public class SearchActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

String JSON_STRING,sq,js_username,js_first_name,js_last_name,js_avatar;
EditText et_sq;
private static final String json_user_search_url = "http://www.domain.com/string.php";
private static final String TAG = SearchActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private List<SearchResults> movieList = new ArrayList<SearchResults>();
private ListView listView;
private CustomListAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewSearch);
    adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, movieList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    // Creating volley request obj
    JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(json_user_search_url, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());

                    // Parsing json
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        try {

                            JSONArray responseArray = response.getJSONArray("server_response");
                            JSONObject content = responseArray.getJSONObject(0);
                            SearchResults movie = new SearchResults();
                            movie.setUser_name(obj.getString("user_name"));
                            movie.setFirst_name(obj.getString("first_name"));
                            movie.setLast_name(obj.getString("last_name"));
                            movie.setAvatarUrl(obj.getString("avatar"));

                            // adding movie to movies array
                            movieList.add(movie);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }

                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            System.out.println(error.getMessage());
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());

        }
    });

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response is a JSON object with "server_response" being it's only value. "server_response" itself is a JSONArray wrapped by a JSONObject, so you need to change:

```
new JsonArrayRequest(json_user_search_url, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
```

to:

```
new JsonObjectRequest(json_user_search_url, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
```

as well as overriding onResponse:

```
@Override
public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
```

And then you can access the response and get the "server_response" without looping through the contents like you are:

```
@Override
public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
    JSONArray responseArray = response.getJSONArray("server_response");
    JSONObject content = responseArray.getJSONObject(0);
    String firstName = content.getString("first_name");

    //get rest of the objects similarly...
}
```

EDIT: Made a mistake in the original answer. "server_response" is a JSONArray containing a JSON object at index 0. You access the JSONObject and store it's content an object, then extract the key/value pairs for it's data.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I edited the question. Can you please read it again? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I see the edit but you didn't make the changes I told you to do. Your API is returning a response that is a JSONObject NOT a JSONArray. The JSONArray in this case is "server_response" which is wrapped in a JSONObject.

Comment: Scratch that. I'm testing it now.

Comment: Also, it is only showing one set in the JSON array. If I have two people, for example bob and jack, it only shows one on the XML sheet. Can you point me to the right direction as of where to go to make it loop to display everyone? As you can see in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XWso6AWFsZw , it shows many "movies", not just one.

Comment: Instead of getting JSONObject at 0 loop through each JSONObject in responseArrays length

Comment: Hint: you were almost doing  this in original  code